#  Existence of algebraic closure and Axiom of choice

Tags: axiom-of-choice, set-theory, fields, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is the statement that every field has an algebraic closure known to be equivalent to the ultrafilter lemma?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46566/is-the-statement-that-every-field-has-an-algebraic-closure-known-to-be-equivalent)
>   [algebraic closure of commuting pairs of matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57719/algebraic-closure-of-commuting-pairs-of-matrices)

we need **zorn's lemma** for proving that every field $F$ has a **unique algebraic closure**. but I haven't seen a converse for this important Theorem.

From the above illustration my question is:

> Is it true that the existence of The  unique algebraic closure is equevalent to **axiom of choice**$(AC)$?

Comment: Take a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46566/is-the-statement-that-every-field-has-an-algebraic-closure-known-to-be-equivalent/46568#46568 and the links given there.

Comment: In particular, the answers over there show that the answer to this question is negative, since the existence of ultrafilters is known to be strictly weaker than AC.

Comment: Ah. Thenk you very much for your notifications. I am sorry for duplication of this Question. I didn't found it in MO.  

Comment: Incidentally, the algebraic closure is not unique.